# android: How to make view fill available space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I couldn't really find an answer for this problem, all I did find was localized questions. Let's say I have this:

[image]

I can successfully do this. However, I want it that if "`BUTTON2`"'s visibility is set to `GONE`, make `BUTTON1`'s width take as much as it can. So it will look like this:

[image]

Currently here's non-working code:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <com.rey.material.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave.Light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="goToOccasion"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/join"
                app:rd_enable="true"
                app:rd_rippleColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:rd_rippleType="wave"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/joinOccasionBTN"
                android:layout_marginStart="87dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/joinOccasionBTN" />

            <com.rey.material.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/joinOccasionBTN"
                style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave.Light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="goToOccasion"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="@string/join"
                app:rd_enable="true"
                app:rd_rippleColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:rd_rippleType="wave"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

That results in this:

[image]

When button2 is `visible`, and it results in the same as the pic above but without button2 ("JOIN").

Comment: May I ask why did I get downvotes? This is a useful non-localized question that is applicable to a large audience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using the `android:layout_weight` attribute in a `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

   <com.rey.material.widget.Button
       android:layout_width=0dp
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight=1
       ...
       />

    <com.rey.material.widget.Button
       android:layout_width=0dp
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight=1
       ...
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

This way, if one of your buttons changes visibility from `visible` to `gone` then the other button will fill the remaining space.

Comment: If you found my question useful, please upvote it to show support

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relativeLayout, use gridView and add your buttons in it. 
If you set on column your button will take all the place.
if you set two columns, gridview will adapt automatically your view to two perfectly sized columns...

two columns :

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</GridView>
```

one column:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:visibility:"gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</GridView>
```

hoping this helps.

Comment: Elaborate your answer by adding an example; not for myself (*I understood it*) but for future readers.  Then I will remove the downvote

Comment: it works, just you wait us to give you the complete cake in your hands.

Comment: It messed the layout up for me, sorry. But since you re-edited your question including proper formatting and a good example I'll reconsider it.

Comment: I don't know, maybe its an error due to the upper layout for me, you can't blame the fact that it isn't working on me. But this is useful for future readers, so +1

Comment: If you found my question useful, please give me an upvote to show support. Otherwise, please inform me of what I can do to make it worthy